# How to print json data into row

Tags: json

I am new in Ajax. I have done a Ajax call and Json is coming like:

```
   [{"id":"4","item_name":"Chalk","unit_price":"2"}]
```

Now i want to print item_name and unit_price in row so i written following code:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var cnt = 1;
jQuery('#addItem').on('click', function() {
    jQuery("#items").show();

    var item_id = jQuery('#classlist1').val();
    jQuery.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php?option=com_notifint&task=getIteminfo&format=raw&tmpl=component&item_id='+item_id,


        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
             alert(data);
              var json_x = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

            var iname = json_x['item_name']
            alert(iname);

            jQuery("#items tbody:first").append('<tr class="item-row"><td>' + cnt + '</td><td>' + iname + '</td><td><class="cost">' + uprice + '</td><td><input class="qty" value="0" /></td><td><span class="price">0</span></td><td><div class="delete-wpr"><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td></tr>');

            cnt++;

        }

    });
});
```

});

but it takes iname value blank
so please tell me solution.
Taks in advance.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Only takes 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

`json_x` is an array, you need to index it:

```
var iname = json_x[0].item_name;
```

Also, don't call `JSON.stringify(data)`, since the response is already in JSON format. It should be:

```
json_x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: still alert is coming blank

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

var json_x = JSON.Parse(data);